# Should I make a Web Service with REST

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, rest

I have made a web application that administrate questions for a quiz. The web content is divided into two pieces; One administrating part, and one public part. These interfaces are made for desktop web browsers.

Now, I want mobile devices to be able to browse these questions (with the look and feel of an application).

So I thought of two ways I could do it; Just add another folder in the webcontent named `mobile` make a custom interface for mobile phones and just add a webview with that URL in Android/iOS etc.

Or, make a Web Service using REST and make a new web application that is interdependent of the question project and act just as a client of it using the REST services.

Does one of the approaches above seem reasonable, or are there other better ways of doing it?

---

**Update**
This is a project made with EJB and JSF. Should I just add a folder in the JSF project and point mobile phones to that?

Comment: I would think about creating a html5 app with jQuery to create a nice sliding effect etc for the questions.
It seems like creating a webservice and a phone app is a lot of work

Comment: @Thomas So would you just add another folder in the same project named mobile and then make a html5 application?

Comment: Yes i probably would, though i'm not completely sure you can do this withouth a webservice. I haven't tried using html5 in business applications yet.

my ideal setup would be something like this:

open webservice for public access and mobile apps (mostly to just read data)
authenticated webservice for administration

administration front end in whatever language you like
public front end in whatever language you like
mobile apps for each platform OR a html5 app for mobile (depending on how much u rely on graphics or platform specific features)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is typical [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) application where you need to have two type of views

1. HTMl view for your browser based clients
2. XML view for Mobile applications (achievable by REST as you mentioned).

I would suggest to have a native mobile application which would talk to the web server via REST APIs.

Not sure which framework you are using here but most of the MVC framework will allow you to create XML views (Please check [struts2 rest plugin](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/rest-plugin.html))

Now the overall idea/design should be :

- The web controllers/Actions  talk to delegates
- The delegates in turn talk to DAOs
- DAOs talk to Database.

You will have different controllers for different end users (html for browsers/xml mobile)

Answer (score 0):

Check out ft.com on your iPad, may be Android powered tablet might work as well. I believe this website will demonstrate the richness of HTML5/CSS3 based application.

On the other side there are certain advantages of making native applications but the problem is that you will have to create your app multiple times for different kind of platforms.

There is one solution to the problem above, you can use something similar to Appcelerator Titanium where you will do your coding in Javascirpt and their cross compiler will create native apps for you, if nothing, it's worth looking at once.

Comment: Ok, so you would just add another folder in the EJB/WEB project named mobile for example and call the services I need directly?

Comment: @Pjotr It's your decision to make, you can use HTML5 or Use Titaniium. For Html you can create a different folder for Titanium, you will have to create a different project using that technology and go through the appsoter/market mechanism,

Comment: But you have misunderstood the question. Should I do this in the already existing project with EJBs and JSF, or should I make another project?

Comment: @Pjotr Oops, I am so sorry... Is there a reason not to create a separate project? One top of my head in favor is, if your web/app server goes down your mobile website will go down as well. Are you ok with that?

Comment: But how would you get the data from it then?